# XMLHttpRequest is not working on chrome version 23 & above

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I have created the chrome extension & added the crx file into chrome extension section.This .crx file was created using javascript & manifest.json files.From java script,i am giving XMLHttpRequest to my java servlet  after every 10 sec time interval.I have tested this on chrome version 18 &19,its working properly but when i am trying to add .crx file in chrome version 23 then XMLHttpRequest not working.
 The javaScript code is :-

```
try{


    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       /* document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;*/
       // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
          if(xmlhttp.responseText!="?"){
              chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text : xmlhttp.responseText});
              chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/IconGreen.png"});
              chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color : [ 208, 0, 24, 255 ]});
          }
          else{
              chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text :"?"});
              chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/IconGrey.png"});
              chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor( {color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          }
        }
      };
    xmlhttp.open("GET"," http://127.0.0.1:8888 /engile/realTimeUpdateCountServlet",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);

}
```

& manifest.json is

```
{

  "name": "A Chrome Extension",
  "version": "4.4.0", 
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs",
    "webNavigation", 
    "http://*/*",
    "chrome.action"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "278CB17EDF811DAFF4CBD7790CBE8C06.cache.html"
  ],  
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Make this page red",
    "default_icon": "images/IconGrey.png"

  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Please give me any suggestion on it.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in you code

- `"browser_action": { "name": "Make this page red"`, there is no argument called **name**, it has to be `"default_title"`
- `"permissions": ["tabs","webNavigation", "http://*/*", "chrome.action"],` there is no permission called `chrome.action` add a relevant permission from **[documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)**.

Comment: Hi Sudarshan,I have changed the manifest.json file as you suggested.But still it not working on the chrome 23.

Comment: @dhananjay:Can you post your updated code by editing your question.